# What limits the implementation of proximity operators for text indexing and searching?

Tags: search-algorithms, data-mining, searching

[I was asking on academia.se](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5079/are-there-hacks-or-smaller-scientific-search-engines-offering-you-context-sensit), if anyone knows scientific search engines offering a [proximity operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_search_%28text%29) like Google Web Search does, while Google Scholar Search does not. That's sad, because this operator would be most useful for literature research offering you a nearly semantic/context-sensitive search and I've seen requests for this feature in many blogs.

The answer on my question linked above shows that 2 search engines offer something similar, but those operators also only work on titles and abstracts of papers, if I understand correctly.

The wikipedia article doesn't explain what exactly limits the implementation of this kind of operator (exponentially rising indexing time, index size,... I'm no search algorithm expert), but when Google Web Search offers it (the amount of web-text is much bigger), what possibly hinders the scientific search engines from offering it for full article text (cost-benefit ratio? I doubt this, as 99,9% of Google Web Search user don't know the AROUND(X) operator and the majority doesn't use [many operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html) at all)?

PS: If this question better fits SO, move it there, but I'm more looking for a general explanation, what parameters determine and limit the implementation of an proximity operator.

Comment: What is wrong with the answers on [academia.SE]?

Comment: @Raphael Nothing, this question is related but different. I'm just curious, for example I want to know, if you need a different bigger index or the proximity operator can use the same one (which I assume), when google offers it for web search. Someone on the linked question was also asking how to implement such an algorithm, what are the difficulties that have to be considered. Thats why I ask. My Desktop Search Engine offes the operator too, I cannot imagine that Google has just "switched off" this operator for Google Scholar?